# Any code issues or other I should be aware of when rerouting a drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent

Central Valley, Hanford, California

I am wondering if there will be any code issues rerouting a drain in the center of the kitchen (4" cast-iron) to an exterior wall, where a new wall will be built in-front of the exterior wall with 2x6?

I plan on cutting the cast-iron, using a coupling, a 90 long sweep to a 3" reduction and bringing it up through 2x6 floor-sill of the new wall (see image for reference).

[image: enter image description]